# Горизонтальный слайдер на Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Столкнулся с проблемой слайдера, как реализовать длинну слайдера, что бы он не листал пустые поля справа и слева. Проблема проявляется когда листаешь до конца слайдера + когда возвращаешься к 1 элементу, появляется большой отступ.

Как я понимаю, он берет ширину шага в 100px. Как можно сделать что бы он брал ширину самого

и делал шаг именно с шириной

?

Спасибо.

Первоначальный вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После прокрутки до конца в право:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После возврата к началу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var view = $("#tslshow");
var rightArrow = $("#rightArrow");
var leftArrow = $("#leftArrow");
var move = "100px";
var sliderLimit = -750;
var fullWeight = 0;

$('#tslshow li').each(function() {
 fullWeight+=$(this).width();
});

if(fullWeight < $('#viewContainer').width()) {
 rightArrow.addClass('hide');
 leftArrow.addClass('hide');
} else {
 rightArrow.removeClass('hide');
 leftArrow.removeClass('hide');
}

rightArrow.click(function(){
    var currentPosition = parseInt(view.css("left"));
    if (currentPosition >= sliderLimit) {
  view.stop(false,true).animate(
   {left:"-="+move},
   {duration: 400}
  ) 
 }
});

leftArrow.click(function(){
    var currentPosition = parseInt(view.css("left"));
    if (currentPosition < 0) {
  view.stop(false,true).animate(
   {left:"+="+move},
   {duration: 400}
  )
 }
});
```

```css
.bstimeslider {
width: 100%;
height:40px;
background:#fff;
position:relative;    
}

.bktibx {
    
float:left;
margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
font-size:18px;
display:block;
background:red;
color:#fff;
    
}

#tslshow {
position:absolute;
left:0;
width:1200px;
   
}

#leftArrow {
    
width:20px;
height:20px;
position:absolute;
top: 20px;
left:0px;
}

#rightArrow {
    
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right:0px;
}

#leftArrow.hide, #rightArrow.hide {
display: none;
}

#viewContainer {
width:95%;
height:100%;
background:#ffffff;
position:absolute;
left:20px;
overflow:hidden; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs small-tabs bstimeslider">
  <div id="rightArrow"><img src="images/arrow_right.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
  <div id="viewContainer">
    <div id="tslshow">
      <li class="active bktibx"><a href="#tabTaglia1" data-id="tabTaglia1"><span>Taglia S</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"><a href="#tabTaglia2" data-id="tabTaglia2"><span>Taglia M</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
      <li class="bktibx"> <a href="#tabTaglia3" data-id="tabTaglia3"><span>Taglia L</span></a> </li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="leftArrow"><img src="images/arrow_left.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: слайдер же не работает

Comment: @Demon__ANT его нельзя тут запустить просто. Огромный кусок CSS подумал что лучше не вставлять

Comment: Проще использовать слайдер из jquer.ui
Как вам такой вариант? Там изначально всё настроено, а стили можно поменять, как вам хочется

Comment: загрузите весь код чтобы люди увидели что как рабоатет и что вам надо.Потому что так никто не поможет